# Docker ssh, back to container showing unexpected results

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-container

I'm studying the Docker documentation, but I'm having a hard time understanding the concept of creating a container, ssh, and ssh back.

I created a container with
`docker run -ti ubuntu /bin/bash`

Then, it starts the container and I can run commands. `docker ps` gives me

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
0e37da213a37        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       keen_sammet
```

The issue is after I exit the container I can't ssh back.
I tried `docker attach` that gives me `Error: No such container` and I tried `docker exec -ti <container>/bin/bash` that gives me the same message `Error: No such container`

How do I run and ssh back to the container?

Comment: What do you mean by *ssh back*? There seems not be a ssh server involved in your scenario. Actually, using ssh in Docker is usually considered a bad practice.

Comment: I think I had a different idea of containers. I was imaging a use similar to a VM environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `exit` the bash process, the container exits (in general, a container will exit when the foreground process exits).  The error message you are seeing is accurately describing the situation (the container is no longer running).

If you want to be able to `docker exec` into a container, you will want to run some sort of persistent command.  For example, if you were to run:

```
docker run -ti -d --name mycontainer ubuntu bash
```

This would start a "detached" container. That means you've started `bash`, but it's just hanging around doing nothing.  You could use `docker exec` to start a new process in this container:

```
$ docker exec -it mycontainer ps -fe
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 16:28 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root        17     0  0 16:28 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -fe
```

Or:

```
$ docker exec -it mycontainer bash
```

There's really no reason to start `bash` as the main process in this case, since you're not interacting with it.  You can just as easily run...

```
docker run -ti -d --name mycontainer ubuntu sleep inf
```

...and the behavior would be the same.

The most common use case for all of this is when your `docker run` command starts up some sort of persistent service (like a web server, or a database server, etc), and then you use `docker exec` to perform diagnostic or maintenance tasks.

The `docker attach` command will re-connect you with the primary console of a detached container.  In other words, if we return to the initial example:

```
docker run -ti -d --name mycontainer ubuntu bash
```

You could connect to *that* bash process (instead of starting a new one) by running:

```
docker attach mycontainer
```

At this point, `exit` would cause the container to exit.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't ssh to a docker container (unless you have a sshd process in that container). But you can execute a command with ***docker exec -ti mycontainer bash -l***

But you can exec a command only on running container. If the container exited already you must use another approach : create an image from the container and run a new one.

Here is an example. First I create a container and create a file within then I exit it.

```
$ docker run -ti debian:9-slim  bash -l
root@09f889e80153:/# echo aaaaaaaaaa > /zzz
root@09f889e80153:/# cat /zzz 
aaaaaaaaaa
root@09f889e80153:/# exit
logout
```

As you can see the container is exited (Exited (0) 24 seconds ago)

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
09f889e80153        debian:9-slim         "bash -l"                45 seconds ago      Exited (0) 24 seconds ago                            thirsty_hodgkin
```

So I create a new image with ***docker commit***

```
$ docker commit 09f889e80153 bla
sha256:6ceb88470326d2da4741099c144a11a00e7eb1f86310cfa745e8d3441ac9639e
```

So I can run a new container that contains previous container content.

```
$ docker run -ti bla bash -l
root@479a0af3d197:/# cat zzz 
aaaaaaaaaa
```